# bootstrap embed-responsive does not work with css column count?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, column-count

bootstrap embed-responsive does not work with css column-count. For example:

```css
/** Divide the target element into <number> columns */
.columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    /*-webkit-column-fill: auto;*/

    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    /*-moz-column-fill: auto;*/

    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 15px;
    /*column-fill: auto;*/
}

.video-box {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="video-box">
            <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qYv5R_e5hTM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="video-box">
            <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/feQ99SuGdsw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="video-box">
            <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r_KEWddTrVc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

The second and the third videos are being not displayed!

Any ideas why and how I can get around to it?

**NOTE:**

It seems it is a bug on Chrome. Firefox is fine.

Comment: which browser you are using, I'm able to see all three videos in their respective section. http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/wWMOpM

Comment: i think it is a bug on chrome....

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use the jquery plugin from http://masonry.desandro.com/ to fix this bug. Just forget about `column-count`!